# Map a function to irregular matrix column major_order

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have an irregular matrix

```
mat = {{"a"}, {"b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i", "j"}, {"k", "l", "m", "n", "o"}};
```

I need map a function to the previous N elements, by default, row priority

```
Block[{c = 0}, Map[If[c++ < 6, Framed[#], #] &, mat, {2}]] // Grid
```

[image]
How to make the column priority? And the original list is unchanged, the output should be
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mat = TakeList[CharacterRange["a", "o"], Range[5]];

Grid @ mat
```

[image]

You can use [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) to map `Framed` at desired list of indices:

```
indexlist = Join @@ MapIndexed[#2 &, mat, {2}];

MapAt[Framed, mat, Take[indexlist, 6]] // Grid
```

[image]

Simply sort `indexlist` by last elements to get *column priority*:

```
MapAt[Framed, mat, Take[SortBy[Last] @ indexlist, 6]] // Grid
```

[image]

**Note:** You can also get the index list using `Position`:

```
indexlist == Position[mat, _String] == Position[mat, _, {2}, Heads -> False]
```

> True

We can play with different functions to sort-by

```
sortfuncs = {"First", "Last", "-First@#&", "-Last@#&", "-Subtract@@#&", 
   "Subtract@@#&", "Max", "-Min@#&", "Mod[First@#,2,1]&", 
   "-Mod[Last@#,2]&", "Ratios", "-Ratios@#&"};

Grid[Partition[
 Labeled[
     Grid[MapAt[Highlighted, mat, Take[SortBy[ToExpression @ #] @ indexlist, 6]], 
       ItemSize -> {2, 2}, ItemStyle -> FontSize -> 14], 
     Style[#, 16, Black], Top] & /@ sortfuncs , 4], 
 Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
 ItemSize -> {15, 15}, 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

mat = {{"a"}, {"b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i", "j"}, 
  {"k", "l", "m", "n", "o"}};

Block[{c = 0, n = 6},
  Transpose[
    PadLeft[
     Map[If[c++ < n, Framed[#], #] &,
      Transpose[
        PadRight[mat, Automatic, $pad]] /.
       $pad :> Nothing,
      {2}],
     Automatic, $pad]] /.
   $pad :> Nothing] // Grid
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
m = 
 {{"a"}, 
  {"b", "c"}, 
  {"d", "e", "f"}, 
  {"g", "h", "i", "j"}, 
  {"k", "l", "m", "n", "o"}};
```

Using `CopyListStructure`

```
CLS = Internal`CopyListStructure;

CLS[m, MapAt[Framed, ;; 6] @ Flatten @ m] // Grid
```

[image]

```
CLS[
  m,
  ReplaceAll[{x_} :> x] @ SortBy[Last] @
    MapAt[List, 7 ;;] @ MapAt[Framed, ;; 6] @ Flatten[m, {2, 1}]
  ] // Grid
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
m = 
 {{"a"}, 
  {"b", "c"}, 
  {"d", "e", "f"}, 
  {"g", "h", "i", "j"}, 
  {"k", "l", "m", "n", "o"}};
```

---

Using `SubsetMap`:

**Case 1**

```
index = Thread /@ MapIndexed[List, m, {-1}];

pos = Take[Catenate[Last /@ index], 6];

elem = Take[Catenate[First /@ index], 6];

SubsetMap[Framed /@ elem &, m, pos] // Grid
```

[image]

**Case 2**

```
pos = Take[SortBy[Last]@Catenate[Last /@ index], 6];

elem = Extract[First /@ index, pos];

SubsetMap[Framed /@ elem &, m, pos] // Grid
```

[image]